# Rust mutably borrowed lifetime issue

Tags: rust, lifetime

This is en excerpt from my actual code, but the issue is the same. I cannot borrow the `staging_buffer` in `Buffer::from_data` as mutable, and I cannot figure out why this is the case. Why isn't the mutable borrow of the `Memory<'a>` from the staging_`Buffer` released when the block is finished?

Note that the `u32` reference in the `Device` struct is just a dummy, and in practice is a non-copyable type.

```rust
pub struct Device<'a> {
    id: &'a u32,
}

impl<'a> Device<'a> {
    pub fn new(id: &'a u32) -> Self {
        Self { id }
    }
}

pub struct Memory<'a> {
    device: &'a Device<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Memory<'a> {
    pub fn new(device: &'a Device) -> Self {
        Self { device }
    }

    pub fn map(&mut self) {}

    pub fn unmap(&mut self) {}

    pub fn copy_from_host<T>(&self, _slice: &[T]) {}
}

impl<'a> Drop for Memory<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

pub struct Buffer<'a> {
    device: &'a Device<'a>,
    memory: Memory<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Buffer<'a> {
    pub fn new(device: &'a Device) -> Self {
        let buffer_memory = Memory::new(device);

        Self {
            device,
            memory: buffer_memory,
        }
    }

    pub fn from_data<T: Copy>(device: &'a Device, _data: &[T]) -> Self {
        let mut staging_buffer = Buffer::new(device);

        {
            let staging_buffer_memory = staging_buffer.memory_mut();
            staging_buffer_memory.map();
            staging_buffer_memory.unmap();
        }

        let buffer = Self::new(device);
        staging_buffer.copy_to_buffer(&buffer);

        buffer
    }

    pub fn memory(&self) -> &Memory {
        &self.memory
    }

    pub fn memory_mut(&'a mut self) -> &mut Memory {
        &mut self.memory
    }

    fn copy_to_buffer(&self, _dst_buffer: &Buffer) {
        //
    }
}

impl<'a> Drop for Buffer<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let id = 5;
    let device = Device::new(&id);
    let _buffer = Buffer::new(&device);
}
```

Comment: `&'a u32` gets you all the pain points of lifetimes with no upside. `u32` is `Copy`, so use plain `u32`. It's faster, equally expressive, and much much simpler. Don't borrow objects that are cheap to copy. (A `&mut` borrow would be a different story.)

Comment: The ownership structure here is a bit confusing. Do you want the `Memory` struct and the `Buffer` struct to possibly have two different devices? If no, you should leave the device only in the `Memory` object. If you actually want different devices to be used, and to be able to reuse the same device, you want to use `std::rc::Rc`.

Comment: Also, for the record, removing the creation of `staging_buffer_memory` and replacing `staging_buffer_memory.map/unmap();` with `staging_buffer.memory.map/unmap();` is enough to fix the issue.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I realise I should've clarified in the question that it is not a u32 in the actual code, but just in this example

Comment: @Marcel You've got a point about the weird ownership of `Device`, it should probably only be in `Memory`, since a `Buffer` is always using the same `Device` as the `Memory` it has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out!

The error here is actually in your implementation of `memory_mut`, and not in the rest of the code (although I agree that the lifetimes and references are making things harder than they need to be).

One way to see that this is the issue is to just mutably borrow `memory` directly, like so.

```rust
...
    pub fn from_data<T: Copy>(device: &'a Device, _data: &[T]) -> Self {
        let mut staging_buffer = Buffer::new(device);

        {
            // Don't use the stagin_buffer_memory variable
            // let staging_buffer_memory = staging_buffer.memory_mut();
            staging_buffer.memory.map();
            staging_buffer.memory.unmap();
        }

        let buffer = Self::new(device);
        staging_buffer.copy_to_buffer(&buffer);

        buffer
    }
...
```

but instead you can fix `memory_mut` by rewriting it like this:

```rust
...
    pub fn memory_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Memory<'a> {
        &mut self.memory
    }
...
```

In this case the implementation of `from_data` works as it should.

Comment: I ended up doing what you suggest in the first code snippet, i.e. just using `memory` directly on `staging_buffer`, but your second suggestion solves it all!! What I don't understand is why it works however. When leaving out the explicit lifetime of `&mut Memory`, what is the elided lifetime? I would've guessed it to be `'a` either way since that is the lifetime of the member variable

Comment: The elision in your original function would expand to `pub fn memory_mut(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut Memory<'a>`, while my suggested implementation expands to `pub fn memory_mut<'b>(&'b mut self) -> &'b mut Memory<'a>`. In the second case the mutable reference to `self` and the mutable reference to the `Memory` can be dropped before the `Memory`. In the first case they must all be dropped at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very confident with this, but I think it is due to the fact that the same lifetime annotation `'a` is used everywhere.
Then, when lifetimes are considered by the borrow-checker, some are supposed to be equivalent (because of the same annotation) although they are not.

A lifetime is indeed necessary for the reference `id` in `Device`.
Another is needed for the reference `device` in `Memory` but this is not necessarily the same as the previous.
Then, I propagated these distinct lifetimes all over the code.

A Rust expert could probably explain this better than me.

```rust
pub struct Device<'i> {
    id: &'i u32,
}

impl<'i> Device<'i> {
    pub fn new(id: &'i u32) -> Self {
        Self { id }
    }
}

pub struct Memory<'d, 'i> {
    device: &'d Device<'i>,
}

impl<'d, 'i> Memory<'d, 'i> {
    pub fn new(device: &'d Device<'i>) -> Self {
        Self { device }
    }

    pub fn map(&mut self) {}

    pub fn unmap(&mut self) {}

    pub fn copy_from_host<T>(
        &self,
        _slice: &[T],
    ) {
    }
}

impl<'d, 'i> Drop for Memory<'d, 'i> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

pub struct Buffer<'d, 'i> {
    device: &'d Device<'i>,
    memory: Memory<'d, 'i>,
}

impl<'d, 'i> Buffer<'d, 'i> {
    pub fn new(device: &'d Device<'i>) -> Self {
        let buffer_memory = Memory::new(device);

        Self {
            device,
            memory: buffer_memory,
        }
    }

    pub fn from_data<T: Copy>(
        device: &'d Device<'i>,
        _data: &[T],
    ) -> Self {
        let mut staging_buffer = Buffer::new(device);

        {
            let staging_buffer_memory = staging_buffer.memory_mut();
            staging_buffer_memory.map();
            staging_buffer_memory.unmap();
        }

        let buffer = Self::new(device);
        staging_buffer.copy_to_buffer(&buffer);

        buffer
    }

    pub fn memory(&self) -> &Memory<'d, 'i> {
        &self.memory
    }

    pub fn memory_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Memory<'d, 'i> {
        &mut self.memory
    }

    fn copy_to_buffer(
        &self,
        _dst_buffer: &Buffer,
    ) {
        //
    }
}

impl<'d, 'i> Drop for Buffer<'d, 'i> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let id = 5;
    let device = Device::new(&id);
    let _buffer = Buffer::new(&device);
}
```

Comment: The only thing that actually needed to be changed was the lifetime of the Memory returned, as in @Marcel 's answer, which you've also done when adding the extra lifetimes. I guess that I should be more careful with what lifetimes I use, instead of just slamming `'a` on everything.